# Flash card book

Tags: substitute-tool

Good afternoon,
I wanted to make a flash card book. Has any one out there made one before?
Anyone with experience and helpful ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a flash card book with a ring binder

[image]

and clear plastic pouches

[image]

perhaps of different colours.

You can

- get them in different sizes, eg. A5, A4
- get them with hard and soft covers
- reorganise their sequence
- add new pages, or update/replace old ones, as an ongoing process

<sub>*images from Amazon*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

**Divide & Conquer Hack**

Rather than create a **book** of flashcards (aka a notebook), make, use, and keep them as a **deck** of individual cards each with an association you wish to learn.

A notebook imposes a sequence to your learning. The concept of flash cards strengthens factual association rather than procedures, say. Changing the order of review and greater repetition with more challenging ones is helpful—easier if cards are loose.

Make them yourself adds to your learning of each one. Commit your answer (say out loud or write answer) before you peek. Work with a partner if you can.

Good luck.